# Android customized adapter with both editText and textView

Tags: java, android, adapter

I'm trying to implement an Android app for sudoku game, and i created a customized adapter for that. i want make edit text for cells the user is allowed to modify, and textview for cell filled by the program, the number of ediTexts and textViews will be random. how do specify that in the adapter ?

This is my adapter :

```
public class SodukuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> items;


    static Activity mActivity;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public SodukuAdapter (Activity activity, ArrayList<String> tempTitle,) {
        mActivity = activity;
        items = tempTitle;


        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public final int getCount() {

        return items.size();

    }

    @Override
    public final Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public final long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = null;

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et);
        et.setText(items.get(position));

        return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place both views in the same parent (e. g. parent is a `RelativeLayout` or a `FrameLayout`) so they are on top of each other. Than you simply hide one of them and show the other using `setVisibility()` in your `getView()` method of the adapter.

Of course you would need a datasource object which keeps track of whether a view should show the `TextView` or the `EditText`:

```
class SodokuItem {
    public boolean isStatic;
    public String text;
}

...

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)     {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    SodokuItem item = items.get(position);

    EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);

    if(item.isStatic){
        et.setVisibility(GONE);
        tv.setText(item.text);
    }else{
        tv.setVisibility(GONE);
        et.setText(item.text);
    }

    return v;
}
```